# Select from Drop down list in Internet Page

Tags: vba, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

ı am new vba and here. I am working on stocks and ı need your helps.
so firstly as you can see on tittle, ı want to choose automaticly in down list what i write on my excel. So ı need amortization information from this web site [website](https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/Sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse=EGEEN) in "MALİ TABLOLAR"page amortization in turkish is amortisman and it is the end of the page.The cods that ı write working halfway
ı can go just "mali tablolar" page and ı cant choose date from down list.

```
Sub Düğme2_Tıkla()
sirketismi = Range("A2")
```

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/Sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse=" & sirketismi)

```
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document

Do Until Not ie.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
ie.document.all("page-4").Click
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE





End Sub
```

[html code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KURRp.png)
 [my excel link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nL9AZ7anhytz0vyMh8tObVkXVImof9xJ)

in epitome, i will write to a2 cell and this macro will take amortization info with correct date.
Sorry for bad english.
I hope you understand me
thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works

```html
For i = 0 To ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1
If ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(i).innerText = "Amortisman Giderleri" Then
result = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(i + 1).innerText
Range("B11").Value = result
End If
Next i
```

Comment: This appears to be an answer to a new question rather than an answer to your existing posted question

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid opening a browser and use a faster method. That pages constructs a querystring which it uses in [xhr requests](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) to update the table values. The response is json you can parse. For example with the left and right drop downs set as follows you can view the xhr in the network tab

[image]

Example of the query string parameters:

[image]

The left dropdown generates:

[https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/*layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=6&*=1547055336791](https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/_layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=6&_=1547055336791)

The right generates:

[https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/*layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=3&*=1547055336792](https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/_layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=3&_=1547055336792)

Note that the currency is defined by (`mn $` versus `mn TL`):

`exchange: USD`  or `exchange=TRY`

Using [JSONConverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the json, and adding the .bas to the project as well as reference via vbe > tools > references > `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, you can parse out the values from the JSON. A reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` is also required.

E.g. **json response** for first url

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, col As Collection
    Set html = New HTMLDocument: Set col = New Collection
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/_layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=6&_=1547055336791", False
        .send
         col.Add JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("value")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/_layouts/15/IsYatirim.Website/Common/Data.aspx/MaliTabloShortTable?companyCode=EGEEN&exchange=TRY&year1=2018&period1=3&_=1547055336792", False
        .send
        col.Add JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("value")
    End With
    EmptyDict col
End Sub

Public Sub EmptyDict(ByVal col As Object)
    Dim item As Object, item2 As Object
    For Each item In col
       For Each item2 In item
        Debug.Print item2("KT_TANIMI"), item2("value1")
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: my friend thanks for your comment but ı have been learing vba just few days and your comment is so hard to understand for me :( so ı guess ı should learn vba-json language

Comment: Yes. But if you later have specific questions on the code please ask.

Comment: Yes. As I show above. It is written in vba. It requires a little understanding of xmlhttp and Json. In Json [] denotes a collection you For Each over and {} is a dictionary you loop the keys of.

Comment: I think I've used that same JSON Parser before :D. Still, parsing JSON in VBA is not  a fun task

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs  that’s how I feel about Json and python at present. I think I must have missed a trick somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

ı did it with `

```html
Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
    Set evtChange = HTMLdoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evtChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    Set selectElement = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ddlMaliTabloDonem1")
     selectElement.Value = Range("B2")
     selectElement.dispatchEvent evtChange`
```

its working now but now there is a another problem :D

ı wanna take data "amortisman giderleri" but ı dont know how can ı take data from td(witout java pls :D)

https://hizliresim.com/nQEN6a